# implicit value not found

Tags: scala, implicit

```
class Test {
    import scala.collection._

    class Parent
    class Child extends Parent

    implicit val children = mutable.Map[String, Child]()

    def createEntities[T <: Parent](names: String*) = names.foreach(createEntity[T])


    def createEntity[T <: Parent](name: String)(implicit map: mutable.Map[String, T]): Unit = map.get(name) match {
        case None => println( name + " not defined.")
        case _ =>
    }
}
```

Why the compiler complains:

error: could not find implicit value for parameter map: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,T]
names.foreach(createEntity[T])

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you call, e.g., `createEntities[Parent]("A", "B")` (which you can, because `Parent` is a subtype of `Parent`), it needs an implicit `mutable.Map[String, Parent]`, and there isn't one. To be more precise, your definitions require you to supply a `mutable.Map[String, T]` for *every* subtype of `Parent`, not just those already defined:

```
implicit def aMap[T <: Parent]: mutable.Map[String, T] = ...
```

Comment: It's the `names.foreach(createEntity[T])` call which requires an implicit argument. If you remove this call, of course it compiles!

Comment: Got it. It is legal to call : createEntity[Child]() but not createEntity[T]() because there is an implicit value for mutable.Map[String, Child] but none for mutable.Map[String, T]